# Dax measure value constant for all entities

Tags: powerbi, dax

If I have a simple table as below

```
Department    User  Sale
    IT         A      25
    IT         B      25
    DA         C      25
```

Is it possible to create a measure that would keep the sum of `sale` fixed for each User. So that in a table visual it would appear as:

```
 Department   User  SaleMeasure
    IT         A     50
    IT         B     50
    DA         C     25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need to remove the `User` filter context if you don't want to use it.

```
SalesMeasure = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Sale]), ALL(Table1[User]))
```

---

This matches your stated output either as a measure or a calculated column:

[image: SaleMeasure]
[image: SaleColumn]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it did not work for me. I probably didnt reveal enough details. I've updated my question. It would basically still at 25 for each hirarchy/employee.

Comment: @vandelay It works for the data you've provided as demonstrated in the screenshots I added.

Comment: Ah thank you. I see that now, I had a cross filter on both on a relationship that messed it up. Guess that's another question :p